# Representing players with 1..N coords in Java

Tags: java

my question is how would you do it to make a code as,

i need a list with players[unique] and for every player i got these coords [x, z]

but for every player there can be more than 1 coordinates[x,z]

i need to save it easly and i have to check the coords of the players every time they trigger an event...

so i have no idea where to start

my english aint good so i gonne try to draw it a little for you hehe

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything? Is this a homework?

Comment: In which way do you have to check the coordinates? It makes a difference for the implementation to choose. Could you add more details on what this game is about?

Comment: it isnt a homework ;)   There is an event like a button click and then i get the playername and the current coords they are one, now i like to check if they own them... so i get the playername and the coords they are on when they pressed the button... also when they trigger an event then id like to add the current coords where they on lets say another button... again i get the current coords and their name. there will be alot of checking coords so it has to be fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one is resolved

made 2 classes Coordinate and Player  and made in player an arraylist of coordinate

in the main class i make an arraylist of player...

Saving happens with xml

thx anyway for the help !

Answer (score 0):

For every player, store the coordinates list in an ArrayList (where Point is a structure that holds the (x,y) coordinates--perhaps java.awt.Point). Make Point implement [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). (java.awt.Point already implements Serializable.) Also make the player class implement Serializable. Then it is easy to serialize and deserialize each player (or an ArrayList of them) using [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)/[ObjectInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

Comment: store the coordinates in an arraylist ok but how :) ? with a class  ? coordinate or just [x,z] and then split them ?